# Pass parameter to pentaho kettle over kettleTransFromFile in pentaho CDE

Tags: mongodb, pentaho

I was used pentaho CE biserver-ce-4.8.0 stable version. I want to create dashboard which fetch data from mongodb, so I was created ktr file in data integration which communicate to mongodb and fetch data from mongodb. After that I was used .ktr file in my CDE dashboard datasource and below was some part in ktr file

```
<hostname>localhost</hostname>
<port>27017</port>
<use_all_replica_members>N</use_all_replica_members>
<db_name>${db_name}</db_name>
<fields_name/>
<collection>test</collection>
<json_field_name>json</json_field_name>
<json_query/>
<auth_user/>
<auth_password>Encrypted </auth_password>
<auth_kerberos>N</auth_kerberos>
<connect_timeout/>
<socket_timeout/>
<read_preference>primary</read_preference>
<output_json>Y</output_json>
<query_is_pipeline>N</query_is_pipeline>
<execute_for_each_row>N</execute_for_each_row>`
```

and ${db_name} was my parameter and I want to pass this parameter through url but when  I was passed db_name as url and read that url parameter I got url parameter but my ktr file not understand parameter and hence it was created db in mongo with name ${db_name} so I was passed parameter to ktr file in pentaho CDE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After going through Pentaho Data Integration 4 Cookbook I found solution of my questions. I solved my problem using following ways.

```
1> First create transformation using PDI and that transformation file add mongodb input.
2> Click on edit->settings and select parameters and add parameter name as db_name.
3> In mongodb input set database name as ${db_name} and set collection name save that transformation file.
4> Now login to pentaho bi server and create new CDE dashboard.
5> go to datasource and select kettle query and add kettle transformation file and add above created ktr file, in variable set arg as db_name and value blank.
6> In same datasource add parameters set name as db_name and value your data base name which you want to pass to ktr file in my case db name as demo.
7> Set above ktr to component panel and it work fine
```

for more ref [click here](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=uS9DAgAAQBAJ&pg=PT617&lpg=PT617&dq=weather_np.ktr%20download&source=bl&ots=oWrGp4BtbQ&sig=ZFn_ym0oGBemPYSdB2nr_uD0Llc&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Bd6xUsrzBIWJrQfSoIGQDg&ved=0CDMQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=weather_np.ktr%20download&f=false)